# Ansible jinja2 if/elif/else construct not working anymore

Tags: ansible

I am using a jinja2 template for creating several files. Those differ a bit dependent on a set variable.

Here's the code:

```
{% if production_env == "prod" or "stage" %}
  password: "{{ group_token }}"
  username: usernamedoesntmatterhere
{% elif production_env == "dev" %}
  password: "{{ mytoken }}"
  username: "{{ mytokenname }}"
{% else %}
    NONE
{% endif %}
```

As you can see when `production_env` is set to `dev` it should template the second block.
It seems that my elif condition is not working anymore.
I used a debug task to get output which variable is set and this is correctly set to `dev`
Ansible renders the first block even if `dev` is set correctly.

That worked fine for months, not sure why it doesn't now.

I already ditched the `elif` block and set it to `else`, even this is not working.

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the condition

```yaml
{% if production_env == "prod" or
      production_env == "stage" %}
  password: "{{ group_token }}"
  username: usernamedoesntmatterhere
{% elif production_env == "dev" %}
  password: "{{ mytoken }}"
  username: "{{ mytokenname }}"
{% else %}
    NONE
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This works! Can you explain why? My code above worked for months and suddenly didn't anymore. I don't get why Ansible templated the first block even with `dev`set as fact for `production_env`

Comment: This could have been working for `"prod" or "stage"` because the string "stage" evaluates to `True`. But `"dev"` could not work because the first option is always `True`.